# What is the minimum acceptable correlation for creating a composite variable?

Tags: correlation, reliability, psychometrics, composite

I have created a composite measure comprising two items (both 7-point Likert scale items), using the summed z score method. The correlation coefficient for these two items is 0.59. This seemed acceptable to me but it is lower than other composite measures I have used in my analysis so reviewers are asking me to justify it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no minimum. It depends on the theoretical construct that you are measuring, and how it relates to the measured variables.

Two examples:

1. I've got two measures that are supposed to measure something associated with intelligence. If they don't correlate highly (0.7? To pick a number out of the air), we've got a problem, and I don't want to sum these.
2. I've got two measures of the amount of potatoes people ate at lunchtime. One of these is fries, one of these is mashed. I'm going to sum these two, to get a 'total amount of potatoes' measure. If these don't correlate negatively, I'm going to be surprised.  But taking the sum will still give  me a measure that matches my theoretical construct.

A reference that might help you is: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232516427_Conventional_Wisdom_on_Measurement_A_Structural_Equation_Perspective